# How to use google-auth-library with Google Cloud Storage with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-api-nodejs-client, google-auth-library

I want to use [Google Cloud Storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage) in NodeJS but authenticate with [google-auth-library](https://googleapis.github.io/google-auth-library-nodejs/index.html) 
Specifically: I want to host this on heroku, so I want to keep the secret in an environment variable, not in a file (as I'd have to commit the file to deploy to heroku). Basically what is suggested in the auth library:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs#loading-credentials-from-environment-variables

But I can't seem to pass the resulting client to the Storage constructor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading the code [[1](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/src/storage.ts#L307),[2](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/src/storage.ts#L47),[3](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-common/blob/master/src/service.ts#L93),[4](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/blob/master/src/auth/googleauth.ts#L55),[5](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/blob/master/src/auth/credentials.ts)]  you should be able to pass in credentials as constructor options:

```
storageOptions = {
  projectId: 'your-project-id',
  credentials: {
        client_email: 'your-client-email',
        private_key: 'your-private-key'
  }
};
client = new Storage(storageOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing, but it's strange the 2 libraries aren't compatible, I would expect to use the fromJson method from the auth library.

Comment: It's especially funny because under the hood the storage lib does use google-auth-library, it just doesn't provide a way for you to pass in the google-auth-library primatives. Might be worth a [feature request](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/new)

Comment: +1 for this approach, dug around the google-auth-library code and the @google-cloud code, can't believe they aren't linked... :(

Comment: I'd also add that you'll need to do some of this `process.env.PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/gm, '\n')` in order to get the correctly formatted private_key

Comment: Just wrote something up - https://medium.com/@sohilpandya/authenticating-google-service-account-securely-and-with-heroku-a0fdc9da9138?sk=f89a4a0b8730c2048a1e9426b09b6f89

Hope it helps someone in the future.